# How to ensure concurrency of http Cloud Function invocations to only one at a time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've setup an Http Cloud Function as backend for a reservation system. This function accesses data from Cloud Firestore retrieving existing time of reservation and to check if the reservation has overlaps from the existing times. This would be no problem if only one concurrent instance of the request can be triggered, however I've noticed that when requesting to the same function from multiple sources at the same time, the function would run those multiple request in a somewhat parallel way based on my log.

Here is a snippet of my function below:

```
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const { stand_id, user_id, reservation } = data;
  const isReservationValid = await checkAvailability(reservation, stand_id);

  if (!isReservationValid) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('aborted', 'Errr');
  }

  return await createReservation(stand_id, user_id, reservation);
});
```

The problem arises if I call this function and pass in the same stand_id, and overlapping reservation times, I've noticed that the function wouldn't wait for the whichever is the first function to get invoked to finish before starting the subsequent requests.

Is there a way I can solve this problem better? Or any workaround?
Or did I just misunderstood the documentation below?:
[image: Doc screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't arrange for only once function to be invoked at a time.  You should expect that Cloud Functions will [scale up multiple server instances to handle load](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec), then scale them down when they're no longer needed.  This is an important feature of Cloud Functions, since the system absolutely needs to scale under load.

The documentation you're referring to is saying that a single Cloud Functions instance can only handle one request at a time.  But you need to first read and understand the first paragraph in that section, as this behavior will never change:

> Cloud Functions may start multiple function instances to scale your
>   function up to meet the current load. These instances run in parallel,
>   which results in having more than one parallel function execution.

If your functions need to write to Firestore in your function, and those functions might be writing to the same document, you need to use a transaction to make sure each of those updates do not overwrite each other in a way that causes data loss.

Comment: thank you, do you know of any current Google Cloud Platform that might be easy to handle these kinds of situations or problem? If so can you suggest :(

Comment: Cloud products are meant to scale massively.  Running something only one at a time is not very scalable.  You'll have to implement something yourself in a container that intentionally doesn't scale.

Comment: It is nowadays possible to limit the maximum number of instances Cloud Functions will spin up: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Unfortunately, it's not a hard limit. According to those docs in the section [Traffic Spikes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#traffic_spikes): *"In some cases, such as rapid traffic surges, Cloud Functions may, for a short period of time, create slightly more instances than the specified max instances value. If your function cannot tolerate this temporary behavior, you may want to factor in a safety margin and set a lower max instances value than your function can tolerate."*

Comment: And as a continuation for Firebase developers… It is possible to configure `maxInstances` for the Firebase cloud function in the source code. See [this reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_configuration_.runtimeoptions#maxinstances), should be used like `export const myFunction = functions.runWith({ maxInstances: 1 }).…`. However, the [Guides section of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) does not cover this property yet. Maybe @DougStevenson or @Frank could facilitate fixing this.